# VBA move files based on string in filename

Tags: vba, string, file, filenames, move

We receive Word files containing the ISO 3-letter country code as a string in the filename. We want to move these files from a holding folder to an existing folder for each country that is named by country name.

I have been going round in circles trying to get `InStr` to work. `InStr` is preferable, because the position of the string in the filename can change.

Could someone please advise what is wrong with my code? It runs, but does nothing.

Also there are a lot of country files (60+ ISO codes). Is there a smarter method than `For Each` and `ElseIf`?

Many thanks!

```
Sub MoveFiles_SpecificFolders()

Dim SrepFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim Srep As File
Dim HldFolder As Folder
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String
Dim Fname As String

Fname = (HoldingFolder & "*.doc*")

HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\Temp\Test\"
TargetFolder = "C:\Users\DifferentPath\MSfolders\"

Set SrepFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set HldFolder = SrepFSO.GetFolder(HoldingFolder)

For Each Srep In HldFolder.Files

    If InStr(Fname, "ALB") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=TargetFolder & "Albania\" & Srep.Name
    
    ElseIf InStr(Fname, "AND") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=DestinationFolder & "Andorra\" & Srep.Name
    
    ElseIf InStr(Fname, "ARM") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=DestinationFolder & "Armenia\" & Srep.Name
    
    End If
    
Next Srep

End Sub
```

Comment: `Fname = (HoldingFolder & "*.doc*")` - this just means that `Fname` is `"*doc*"` - none of your `InStr` lines will ever evaluate to true.

Comment: I would break it into subtasks. Create a dictionary where the 3 letter code would be the key and the folder name would be the value. Then in a single loop, extract the code, get the folder name from the dictionary and move the file.

Comment: Thanks @Kostas K, that must be the next step now that my simple code is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code with thanks to @BigBen and @Vityata.

```
Sub MoveFiles_SpecificFolders()

Dim SrepFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim Srep As File
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim HldFolder As Folder
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String

HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\Test_docs\"
TargetFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\MSfolders\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SrepFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set HldFolder = SrepFSO.GetFolder(HoldingFolder)

For Each Srep In HldFolder.Files

    If InStr(Srep, "ALB") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=TargetFolder & "Albania\" & Srep.Name
    
    ElseIf InStr(Srep, "AND") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=TargetFolder & "Andorra\" & Srep.Name
    
    ElseIf InStr(Srep, "ARM") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=TargetFolder & "Armenia\" & Srep.Name
    
    ElseIf InStr(Srep, "GEO") <> 0 Then
    SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
    Destination:=TargetFolder & "Georgia\" & Srep.Name
    
    End If
    
Next Srep

End Sub
```

Comment: Finalized version of the macro in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422645/for-each-next-not-looping). Macro modified to avoid using multiple `ElseIf` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Following your code this way:

```
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String
Dim Fname As String

Fname = (HoldingFolder & "*.doc*")

HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\Temp\Test\"
```

The `Fname` variable does not contain the part of the `HoldingFolder`. The `HoldingFolder` variable should be assigned before referred:

```
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String
Dim Fname As String
HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\Temp\Test\"

Fname = (HoldingFolder & "*.doc*")
```

Later in the For-Each loop, you would see a problem here -

`If InStr(Fname, "ALB") <> 0 Then` -> It should be `If InStr(Srep, "ALB") <> 0 Then`

Comment: But the next problem is that `Fname` is never changed or used following assignment. OP should be using `Srep`.

Comment: @BigBen - have to check, replicating the whole thing, but I guess you are right. Anyway, I see it being used here - `If InStr(Fname, "ALB")`. And I guess it should be `Srep` instead of `Fname`...

Comment: Super thanks guys! It works with `Srep`... when I use a consistent path. MUCH appreciated!