# For each... Next not looping

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have a macro that uses a string in the filename to identify the folder to move the file to. It looks up the string in column A and builds the folder name using the country name retrieved from the adjacent cell in column B.

The If statement executes correctly (moves the file correctly). However, the `For each`... `Next` looping through the files doesn't work and I cannot see why not.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Sub MoveFiles_SpecificFolders_Loop()

Dim SrepFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim Srep As File
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String
Dim HldFolder As Folder
Dim i As Integer

HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\Holding\"
TargetFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\Countries\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SrepFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set HldFolder = SrepFSO.GetFolder(HoldingFolder)

    For Each Srep In HldFolder.Files
    
        For i = 2 To 50
   
        If InStr(Srep, Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
        SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
        Destination:=TargetFolder & Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Offset(, 1) & "\" & Srep.Name

        End If
        
        Next i
        
    Next Srep

End Sub
```

Comment: You should be able to step through this line-by-line in the vba debugger. That should make what's wrong clear.

Comment: Thanks @Caleb McNevin - It does - on a rerun (after it has moved the first file) it says `File not found` at `If InStr(Srep, Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0 Then`  - that suggests to me the loop is not working, because it can find the file on the first pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exit the inner for loop once the file has been moved.

Try this

```vb
Sub MoveFiles_SpecificFolders_Loop()

Dim SrepFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim Srep As File
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim HoldingFolder As String
Dim TargetFolder As String
Dim HldFolder As Folder
Dim i As Integer

HoldingFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\Holding\"
TargetFolder = "C:\Users\xyz\Countries\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SrepFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set HldFolder = SrepFSO.GetFolder(HoldingFolder)

    For Each Srep In HldFolder.Files
    
        For i = 2 To 50
   
        If InStr(Srep, Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
            If Not SrepFSO.FolderExists(TargetFolder & Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)) then
                SrepFSO.CreateFolder TargetFolder & Sheet2.Cells(i, 2)
            End if
            
            SrepFSO.MoveFile Source:=SrepFSO.GetFile(Srep), _
            Destination:=TargetFolder & Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) & "\" & Srep.Name
            Exit For
        End If
        
        Next i
        
    Next Srep

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again - I'm pretty sure you are right about the loop within the loop - I know I was getting confused by that! But the `Exit For` means `i` is reset to 2 in the next iteration, which now gives a `Path not found` error.

Comment: It sounds like folder(s) of one or more of the countries don't exist. You need to create these folders before trying to copy files into them. See my updated code. Also note how I got rid of the `Offset` call.

Comment: OK, I have it! The loop stops when `InStr(Srep, Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0` is false. Working on it!

Comment: Many thanks @Caleb McNevin and @Super Symmetry - now working! `ElseIf` added to cover when `If` returns false. MoveFile does not support `Destination` overwriting an existing file, so the macro cannot replace a file with the same name, but I can live with that.

Comment: @ Super Symmetry the reviewers are rejecting my addition of `ElseIf InStr(Srep, Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)) = 0 Then` to your answer and have requested I add this as a comment. The `ElseIf` statement is needed for the loop to run. Could you please add it if you accept.